# Can "who" be plural when it is the subject of a sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, pronouns, verb-agreement, questions

A title I saw reads *Who are doing Jehovah's Will,* which doesn’t sound correct to me. To me, *Who is doing Jehovah's Will* sounds more correct.

Am I wrong, or can both be used in the beginning of a sentence or title?

Comment: What's the full title? "Who" can be plural too.

Comment: If *who* is the subject of the sentence and it is singular, it's: "**Who is doing** [the gardening]?" If instead the subject is *you* the verb must be plural. For example: "**Who(m) are you doing** [business with]?"

Comment: The question lacks context, and is unclear. Please provide the WHOLE sentence, otherwise any answers offered are based only on conjecture and suppositions.

Comment: I edited my question and included the entire title.Thank you

Comment: I'm sorry if you feel you were offended, but nobody has said your question is foolish, I asked that you provided the whole sentence because I saw that your question was going to get closed (and with good reason). The question could now be reopened after your edit. If however, you do not come back and someone is curious to know if @Her Highness Lady Chuthee was correct the answer is that "Who are doing Jehovah's Will" (if that was the complete title) is grammatically correct.

Comment: Thank you@Mari-LouA. I guess I don't quite  understand the down vote and how this site works in general. Who are doing Jehovah's Will is the complete title. It just didnt sound correct to me. your answer has proven to me that the way things sound may not always be  wrong or.right but it's correct Grammar that counts.(was that quoted correctly or made sense)I appreciate your helping me get some understanding of the way this site works and for answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If 'Who' is being used in a plural sense then 'are' is needed (e.g. Who are those people?) otherwise 'is' is used if it is being used in a singular sense (e.g. Who is this person?)

Comment: We really should promote the use of the plural indicator "all", methinks. "Who are doing..." can, sans context, sometimes catch me off guard, but "Who all are doing..." is unambiguous.

Comment: @Arrowfar Thank you for your answer. I didnt know my question would cause such a Hooplah! Being off topic, put on hold and down voted. Whatever for, I have no clue. I just asked a question I didnt know. Guess I won't be coming back here for help! I'm not stupid and there is no such thing as a Stupid question but some people are a little too condescending here. Thanks again. I appreciated your answer. I did edit and include the title in whole. But I have my answer and they can close, down vote, demote or whatever makes them feel good or turned on because I won't be back! Best Regards!

Comment: In "Who are these people," a plural verb is used because the subject of the sentence is "these people." Therefore, it doesn't tell us anything about the grammatical number of "who."

Answer (score 0):

Of course we can only imagine what the rest of the title is, which means if we can come up with something that finishes the sentence and is proper, then the answer is yes, both can be used.

Consider a sports headline:

> Who are doing best on the front nine?

referring to more than one, ie. the leaderboard.

or,

> Who are doing the most to deliver potable water in third-world countries?

Again, referring to more than one.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I edited my question adding the full title. I didnt know I would find a few condescending.folks behind my question. Ok, I asked or formatted my question in a way that is against the rules.So, I get a request to close my question, put on hold and even downvoted! So I thank you for your answer. It was very much appreciated. I doubt that I'll be coming back here again. I'll seek help elsewhere. They can close, hold, down vote all they want to. Get their Rocks off for all I.care! They're no importance to me. Thank You again! Best Regards!