# "Who are" vs "who is"

Tags: grammatical-number, pronouns, verb-agreement

Sentence: it's not what's on the table that matters, but who (is/are) in the chairs.

I thought are might be correct because of plural chairs, but family members disagree.

Comment: Pretty funny how (for me) this is the second google search result for “who are vs who is” and it’s closed as off topic and has a wrong answer.

Answer (score 5):

**Related**: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/22900/who-singular-or-plural

**Closed, nearly-identical question** (off-topic): [Can "who" be plural when it is the subject of a sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/196976/who-is-vs-who-are)

**Relevant discussion**: http://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/340600179/m/7756074182

Who can be both singular or plural dependent on the noun which it is replacing. 'Chairs' in the plural implies that some sentient plural noun will be occupying those chairs.

'Who is' in the chairs would imply a single entity occupying multiple chairs. 'Why are you in my chairs?!' An interesting thought.

'Who are in the chairs?' correctly identifies the chairs' occupants as plural and thus is the correct format.

Comment: But one can indeed ask 'Who are sitting in the chairs?' 'Who is' is also acceptable, but it isn't the only possibility according to anything I've read.

The grammar exchange discussion I linked in my answer (edited in) has some interesting discussion on the topic.

Comment: This answer is wrong. If we can ask *"Who is on the committee"* we should be able to ask *"Who is in the chairs?"* (Unless you think *committee* is synonymous with *dictatorship*.) And we ***can*** ask *"Who is on the committee."* Google it if you don't believe me.

Comment: The possibility of 'who is' as a grammatically correct construction does not eliminate the possibility of 'who are' as a grammatically correct construction. As the answer contains several links, the suggestion to 'Google it' rings hollow.

Comment: What I'm objecting to is the idea that saying *"who is in the chairs"* implies that one person is occupying all the chairs. This is just not true. None of your links say that using *"who is"* for more than one person is incorrect, and at least one says the exact opposite.

Comment: It's an option. I'm a native speaker. The construction in question here has an implicit plural subject. The 'who is' construction isn't ungrammatical. 'Who are' is another option, and when the purpose of the sentence is to convey a sense of community there is little doubt that the chairs are occupied by more than one person.

Comment: Your answer implies that asking [Who is on the committee?](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22who+is+on+the+committee%22) is ungrammatical because you know more than one person is on it. That's wrong. It's perfectly fine English.

Comment: "Who is here?" vs "Who are here?" Google nGrams: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Who+is+here+%3F%2CWho+are+here+%3F&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CWho%20is%20here%20%3F%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CWho%20are%20here%20%3F%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CWho%20is%20here%20%3F%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CWho%20are%20here%20%3F%3B%2Cc0  If 'Who are here?' (an example of a simple interrogative sentence with a plural pronoun) is indeed ungrammatical, it maintains a consistent (limited) usage in literature in spite of that. It's rare, but there are acceptable cases.

Comment: @PeterShor I think committee is a collective noun, therefore making your assumption moot, as collective nouns can be treated as either singular or plural. Correct me if I'm wrong though.

Comment: @IBG An interesting point. http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/collective-nouns Interesting subject.

Comment: @IBG But "committee" is not the subject of the question, "who" is. There's no question, I hope, that "Tom and Harry is on the committee." is wrong. What makes "Who is on the committee?" different, then?

Comment: @hvd 'who is on the committee?' isn't wrong. The subject of who may be singular or plural. Treating the interrogative who as singular is seemingly acceptable in any situation. The debate here is rather about the plural case and when, if ever, it is preferred over the singular.

Comment: @CotyJohnathanSaxman I'm not trying to say it's wrong, merely that it's not at all related to "committee" being a collective noun.

Comment: @Coty the first example of “who are here” in google books is “students who are here from Uganda”. The ? in the search query isn’t a literal question mark, it usually implies the previous character is optional in regular expression syntax, I think in this case it might just be thrown out. If you think you can come into a room and ask “who are here?” and not sound like a weirdo, I question your self characterization as a “native speaker”, at least you’re definitely not from North America.

Answer (score 1):

**[no longer relevant to original question]**

The matter seems to be discussed. Some sources indicate that interrogative form of **who** is [always singular](http://www.write.com/writing-guides/general-writing/grammar/interrogative-pronouns/) *(end of first paragraph: “Interrogative pronouns are never plural”)*.

> Who is in the chairs?

**Who** does the being, it is subject, therefore the verb is singular person.

Now, it might be acceptable to use a plural in some edge cases. In *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language (1985 Quirk et al.)*, page 756:

> Similarly, interrogative who and what as subjects normally take a singular verb even when the speaker has reason to believe that more than one person or entity is involved.
>   However, a plural verb may be used if other words in the sentence indicate that a plural subject is expected in the answer

It is still inadvisable though. For instance, on page 371 of the same book, it says that

> even though several voices are heard outside, the natural question will be Who's there? rather than ?*Who're there?

The ?* sign is used in the book for marking mostly yet not completely unacceptable examples.

Comment: "The interrogative form of who is always singular." Didn't know that. Care to link to more information?

Comment: Unfortunately I only have my English course notes at hand. I must go now, but I guess you could search for "interrogative pronoun' on google. [edit: added a link, first google answer]

Comment: I added a link to a detailed article on interrogative pronouns. First paragraph detail the basic grammar rules, including “*Interrogative pronouns are never plural*”.

Comment: http://www.testden.com/toefl/english-grammar-for-students/Interrogative-Pronouns.html TOEFL guide on interrogative pronouns: "Who is...singular and plural"  http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/pronouns/plural-pronoun-usage.html YourDictionary lists 'who' along with other interrogative pronouns that can be used as plurals.

One style guide (your link) that I found says no. Others are more of the 'situation dictates' stance.

Comment: By the way, the TOEFL link I provided has laughable typographical errors on the page, but it is nonetheless a statement of fact (or stylistic preference?) from a major English language authority.

Comment: Err, check your link, it is not connected to TOEFL whatsoever. Just because some website tells they will help you with TOEFL does not mean it has any kind of endorsement. And seriously, given how that page is littered with spelling and grammar errors, that does not really help making it stand as an *authority*.

Comment: Edited. Now with some authority paper book reference.