# "You who is" OR "you who are"

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, clefts

In the following sentence should it be "you who is" or "you who are"?  I can make a case for either in my mind.  For example, if you turn the sentence around a little bit, you could say, "Tonight, you are the toast of the town. Or you could reimagine it as "The toast of the town is you."  Help - not sure which reasoning is correct.  Thoughts?

> We couldn’t be happier that tonight it is you who IS the toast of the town.

or

> We couldn’t be happier that tonight it is you who ARE the toast of the town.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/216292/who-are-vs-who-is

Comment: I believe the confusion in this question stems from a different source than in the linked question. It is from the fact that "you" is treated as a plural noun. "Who is Rembrandt?" and "who are you?" both ask about a single person's identity, but using "is" and "are" respectively.

So in this case, it would be "you who are the toast of the town."

Comment: Related: [What makes "Remember me, who am your friend" grammatical?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/28662/8019)

Comment: I am, you are, he is, they are.

Answer (score -1):

Your examples of 'Who is/are ...' are appositions.  The subject of the verb is 'who', not 'you', so the plurality is not forced (as it is with 'you').  You should use 'is' or 'are' appropriate to the actual number of people that 'you' represents.  But wait!  Do you ever hear someone say: 'Who are going to run?'  When asking a question, we treat 'who' as singular even when the answer is expected to be plural.  (We expect the answer to be a list.)